# How to overcome repeative blade component queries in laravel

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade

As in laravel we make blade component to reuse that on multiple pages. so for example we have a cardcomponent that has a query in render function

User::count();

and we use that card component on almost every page so whenever a page is loaded the above query is executed again and again. is there a way to overcome it?

Comment: Does it really matter if it executes each time, besides that you may be able to cache it but that depends on the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the query in the AppServiceProvider as shown in the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views. The result will be available in all views and the query should only be executed once.

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Providers;
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
 
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
 
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use a blade component: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components